# VBA - HTMLDocument (Internet Explorer *.website)

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, windows-shell

to get the HTML Document of an opened IE i use the following code:

```
Function getOpenIEByTitle(Title As String) As InternetExplorer
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sh As Object
    Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    For Each getOpenIEByTitle In sh.Windows
        If TypeName(getOpenIEByTitle.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If getOpenIEByTitle.document.Title = Title Then
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This works fine!

BUT:

I can't find the Window if i start a *.website-File with `"iexplore.exe" -w "*.website"`

Can some one help me?

Are there other solutions?

Can i get the HTMLDocument of any running iexplore.exe if i can provide the right PID?

Creating a new InternetExplorer-Application is not a solution for my environment. Or can i start a pinned Website from VBA?

Answer (score 0):

If you know URL or part of URL try this:

```
Public Function GetIEInstance(URLAddress) As SHDocVw.WebBrowser
    Dim objShellWindows as ShDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim ShellWindow as ShDocVw.WebBrowser

    Set objShellWindows = new ShDocVw.ShellWindows

    For Each ShellWindow in objShellWindows
        If InStr(ShellWindow.Name, "Internet Explorer") > 0 Then
            If ShellWindow.LocationURL Like "*" & URLAddress & "*" Then
                Set GetIEInstance = ShellWindow.Application
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next ShellWindow

End Function
```